# How to graph a unit circle using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: unit-circle]

I know some basic graphing like functions on a Cartesian plane or drawing polygons, but how do you graph something like the one above? I also want to put this graph within the unit circle.

Comment: You can just plot them using pgfplots

Comment: Improve your question with you do so far, otherwise this is question do-this-for-me ... As starting point can serve similar picture in TikZ manual.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I recommend you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows what you have tried so far and the specific drawing element that you got stuck on. For instance, can you at least draw the straight lines `AC`, `BC`?

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving your specific problem, instead of just doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area where the `tkz-euclide` package excels:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Set up the canvas
\tkzInit[xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=4.5]

% Clip things outside the canvas
\tkzClip[space=0.5]

% Define two starting points on a horizontal
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}

% Find a point perpendicular to A,C
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal,K=-0.9](C,A)
% Give that new point a name
\tkzGetPoint{B}

% Find the point on the intersection between AC and a circle centered on A passing through B
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(A,B)
\tkzGetSecondPoint{B'}

% It doesn't really make sense to fill the sectors, since we're concerned with angles, not areas
%\tkzDrawSector[fill=BrickRed!40, draw=none](A,B')(B)
%\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=gray!20, draw=none](A,C,B)
%\tkzDrawSector[fill=Dandelion!60, draw=none](A,C)(B)

% Draw the segments
\tkzDrawSegments[gray](A,B A,B')
\tkzDrawSegment[black, very thick](C,B)

% Draw the arcs
\tkzDrawArc[draw=BrickRed, very thick](A,C)(B)
\tkzDrawArc[draw=MidnightBlue, very thick](A,B')(B)

% Label the points
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](C)

% Get the radii of the sectors so we can place the sector labels nicely
\tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B)\tkzGetLength{rAB}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=(\rAB), anchor=south west, text=MidnightBlue](B,A,C){$\theta$}

\tkzCalcLength[cm](A,C)\tkzGetLength{rAC}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=(\rAC), anchor=north east, text=BrickRed!70!black](B,A,C){$\theta\cos\theta$}

\tkzLabelSegment[anchor=west](C,B){$\sin\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```